# Extract data series from a JSON array for a Highcharts chart with 2 y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to create a line chart with 2 y-axis. Below is how I build my JSON array from a MySQL query:

```
$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'V';
$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'Speed';
while($row = $selectQueryResult1->fetch())
{
    $dateTimer1 = ($row['dateTimer']+$timeAdd)*1000;

    $series1['data'][] = array($dateTimer1,$row['v1']);
    $series2['data'][] = array($dateTimer1,$row['speed']);
}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Here is how I call the PHP script in jQuery:

```
$.post('getData.php', {b: begin,e: end}, function(data){

}
```

My issue now is how to extract the `V` data and `Speed` data into two variables because I need to pass them to the chart as two series of data, e.g. I have tried `data[0]`, etc. Nothing seems to work.

```
///chart.series[0].setData( eval(vData) );
///chart.series[0].setData( eval(speedData) );
```

Comment: How your JSON looks like in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add `json` as the 4th argument of your `$.post` to get the JSON parsed as an object, more info here: [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
$.post('getData.php', {b: begin,e: end}, function(data){

}, 'json');
```

Reading your code tells us the structure of your data is as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => V
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => value of $dateTimer1
                            [1] => value of $row['v1']
```

Therefore the data series are:

- `data[0][data]` for `V`.
- `data[1][data]` for `Speed`.

Therefore:

```
chart.series[0].setData( data[0][data] );
chart.series[1].setData( data[1][data] );
```

When in doubt about a structure, simply print it out:

- [`print_r($data);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) in PHP.
- [`console.log(data);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) in JavaScript.

Comment: His spenibus I did like this  data = JSON.parse(data);
             console.log(data[0].data1);
             chart.series[0].setData( eval(data[0].data1) );
              chart.series[1].setData( eval(data[1].data1) ); what is your comments?

Comment: @user5313398 Well obviously `console.log` outputs to the console so you should look there. It should show the object and even be explorable. CTRL+SHIFT+J in at least Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @user5313398 When you set `json` in `$.post` there is no need to use `eval` on the data. It's ready to be used as an array or an object. I updated the answer.